# Why defining the function type in typescript has two ways of doing it?

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between?

Doing:

A)

```
let myAdd: (x: number, y: number) => number =
function(x: number, y: number): number { return x + y; };
```

And just doing this:

B)

```
let myAdd = function(x: number, y: number): number { return x + y; };
```

I took this from the typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type). Why the code in the snippet *A* is useful? I just see some redundance in it, as in just doing as in the snippet *B* the arguments are typed and also the return value is typed.

I'm under the impression that in the snippet *A* the typing of the arguments and the result value is being done twice.

I'm not getting why *A* is different of *B* or why  *A* is more useful than *B*

Comment: It doesn't make a difference because the type being inferred is the exact same. It's often useful to make sure it complies with a specific signature, not with an inline type like this example.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the two examples. In both cases `myAdd` has the same type `(x: number, y: number) => number`.

The examples in the documentation are just about how you write a function type. In this example specifying the type is not particularity useful, but you can do other things with the type. You could put it in a type alias and reuse it:

```
type MyOp = (x: number, y: number) => number;
let myAdd: MyOp = function (x: number, y: number): number { return x + y; };
let mySubtract: MyOp  = function (x: number, y: number): number { return x - y; };
```

You could also not initialize the function on declaration:

```
let myOp: (x: number, y: number) => number;
declare let condition: boolean;

if (condition) {
    myOp = function (x: number, y: number): number { return x + y; };
} else {
    myOp = function (x: number, y: number): number { return x - y; };
}
```

Also when you have a function type you don't need specify parameter types:

```
let myOp: (x: number, y: number) => number = function (x, y) { return x + y;}
```

Answer (score -1):

The 'A' code snippet is basically used to create a type for the myAdd function. If you define the myAdd function without the type, you can reassign to any value or data type afterward. Maybe you want that the myAdd should take two number parameters and return a number. But if you will not assign a type, then you could accidentally assign it to something else.

Comment: I get the exact same error, if I try to assign a diferent type to variables I assign, using the two different functions in the examples, for example If I try assigning a boolean: `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'number'`. So the type of the return type is infered if I use the function in the snippet A or B equally.

Comment: I think you did not understand me. I was talking about reassigning the function itself. For eg: – `let myAdd: (x: number, y: number) => number;
myAdd = true; //Type 'true' is not assignable to type '(x: number, y: number) => number'.`

Comment: Oh, you are right, I haven't understood, but the same error is thrown if you try to reassign the variable in the snippet *B*, for example if I assign the binding to a boolean. for information, this is my tsconfig options:  `    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017"],
        "strictNullChecks":  true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true
    }`

Comment: Using the code snippet 'A' will create a type for myAdd variable. So, if you will reassign it to a different type. It will give an error. `let myAdd: any = function(x: number, y: number): number { return x + y; };myAdd = true // works fine since the type of myAdd is any`.Using the code snippet 'B' will make the Typescript infer the type from the assigned value. In your case, a function that takes 2 number parameters and returns a number and if you will reassign to a different type, it will give an error.